# sending emails in YII2 via contact form sending to another address

Tags: php, email, yii2

I have a problem when sending email messages via the form from the contact tab. I had configure in `web.php` like

```
'mailer' => [                
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',               
    'transport' => [                   
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',                   
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',                  
        'username' => 'email@gmail.com',                  
        'password' => 'PASSWORD',                   
        'port' => '587',                  
        'encryption' => 'tls'               
    ],
    'useFileTransport' => false,
]
```

but when I send a completed form, I do not receive any messages on my inbox. I do not get any error either.
When I check in Yii Debugger, log messages show that:

```
13:14:10.377    info    yii\mail\BaseMailer::send   Sending email "dasdasdasd" to "admin@example.com"
13:14:10.377    info    yii\swiftmailer\Mailer::sendMessage Sending email "dasdasdasd" to "admin@example.com"
```

Why it shows that it sent a message to a different address than what I gave?
Where is problem?

SiteController:

```
public function actionContact() {
    $model = new ContactForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

        return $this->refresh();
    }
    return $this->render('contact', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form']); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'subject') ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'body')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
        'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-3">{image}</div><div class="col-lg-6">{input}</div></div>',
    ]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'contact-button']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: How you're sending this email?

Comment: via default form in contact tab in project.

Comment: @simple_code attach code of sending to the question

Comment: Default form sends emails to mailbox specified in `params.php` in config. This is only an example, you should adjust this form to your needs.

Comment: I have seen some tutorials and I believe that the authors made changes in only one web.php file. How than make than mails send to address from form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account**

To disable this security feature:

1. [Click here to access Less Secure App Access in My Account](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).
2. Next to “Allow less secure apps: OFF,” select the toggle switch to turn ON.

**This setting may not be available for:**

- Accounts with 2-Step Verification enabled: Such accounts require an [application-specific password for less secure apps](http://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/) access.
- G Suite users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has
  locked less secure app account access.

[Source link](https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/)

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom('<fromUsername>@<yourDomain>')
    ->setTo('<user@Email>')
    ->setSubject('Уведемление с сайта <yourDomain>') // тема письма
    ->setTextBody('Текстовая версия письма (без HTML)')
    ->setHtmlBody('<p>HTML версия письма</p>')
    ->send();
```

If you are using localhost, you should "Comment" the swiftmailer settings.For example, for XAMPP, you need to do related settings and you do not need swiftmailer. Configure in (php.ini file - sendmail.ini ).

And for other programs, the necessary settings ...

Comment: I wanted to give a plus but it added a minus. Sorry. Very helpful answer